# Navigation bar button disappears when "Button shapes" enabled

Tags: ios10, navigationbar

When I turn on "Button shapes" option (Settings->General->Accessibility) almost all of buttons placed in Navigation Bar disappear. Even default "Back" buttons.

iOS 10
Xcode 9

Comment: Were the bar buttons programmatically created or were they installed in IB? Please provide some context.

Comment: @the4kman Some buttons are added programmatically, some installed in IB. As I pointed out in the description, system default back buttons disappear as well.